# Do I need to install Composer on server?

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to deploy a Laravel application and wondering if Composer needs to be installed separately on the server?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Questions about managing your servers can be asked on [sf]. Please ask any future questions that are similar to this there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can build your application on a separate server (or less optimal when working in a team, on your development machine) and then copy the project (including the installed vendors) onto your server. In fact it is quite common to build the application on a separate server and then only deploy the artifact (a tar.gz file, an os-package like deb or a built docker image) instead, in order to have a production system without tools/dependencies not required for running the actual application like git, composer, etc.

You might have to run additional commands, e.g. to make sure cache files are generated, but basically you run a `composer install --dump-autoload --no-dev --prefer-dist` (and possibly also `--classmap-authoritative`) to install the production dependencies, run your required artisan commands to copy assets into the public directory, build cache files, etc. and then transfer the whole project over to your server using your preferred method from rsync to any of the other ones mentioned above. There might still be some details you have to take care of, but by no means do you have to have composer installed on your production server.

Answer (score -2):

yes, but it's not necessary to download vendors with `composer install`. you can move composer binary file to Server and move your vendor too,
then place vendor folder on your project and use `composer dump-autoload`.

without Composer you cannot do `dump-autoload`

Comment: 's that means we can't setup application without composer. right?

Comment: Why don't tutorials say to install composer and laravel separately before deplyoing ?

Comment: @LuckySaini Laravel use composer to install, so it needs to run `dump-autoload`

Comment: @Sushant on https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/deployment you can see using composer. on optimization

Comment: "without Composer you cannot do dump-autoload" - why not dump the autoloader locally and deploy the whole `vendor` folder? There is absolutely no need to install Composer on any server

Answer (score -4):

For Laravel application setup, it is compulsory to install `composer` on server. If you are installing application using `git`.

And also in Laravel installation documentation it is written clearly, for Laravel installation and application setup please refer Laravel official documentation `https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/installation#installing-laravel`

One more thing here, as composer is PHP package manager and all the Laravel dependencies can be pulled by composer.

Comment: Can't I just transfer all my files to server using FTP ? and then fix the urls on some files. Won't that work ?  P.S This is my first time deplyoing laravel project on a real server.

Comment: As my understanding you can't deploy application on server without composer. But I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: just following this guide- [https://github.com/petehouston/laravel-deploy-on-shared-hosting] and it doesn't say anywhere to install laravel or composer. Or maybe I'm not getting it properly.

Comment: Of course Composer is not compulsory on your server.  It manages files and packages under `vendor/`, that's all.  If you choose to manage them some other way - like uploading with FTP or committing them in your version control, then you don't need to use Composer.  Personally I don't want to install extra software on my production server and I don't want add another point of failure to my deployment process, so I do *not* have Composer on my server, and I have `vendor/` in git.

Comment: @Don't Panic ... that is a good point. I struggled over this due to conflicting opinions. I finally installed & used it, but then I realized that I am not going to be updating these vendor packages after initial deployment as long as they work correctly. If it ain't broke, don't fix it ... and all that.

Comment: @McAuley Likewise - I update them very, very rarely so having them in git is fine for me.

Comment: "If you are installing application using git" - what does that mean? git won't install any application