# Workaround to install composer on single shared hosting in hostinger

Tags: composer-php, shared-hosting

Without understanding that I needed SSH Access to deploy my Laravel 8 project smoothly, I purchased the Single Shared Hosting tier from Hostinger which does not offer SSH Access. I have to install Composer, but most of the tutorials I have seen requires the use of SSH in doing so.

Deploying the project has to be done before tomorrow morning and I still have no idea what to do next. I am new to this.

Comment: "Now I have to install Composer" - no, you don't have to install Composer on any server. Deploy your project on any development system (where Composer needs to be installed), and properly deploy the application

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need to install Composer on server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53465167/do-i-need-to-install-composer-on-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

- Try to match the PHP version of the server and localhost.
- Install composer locally. This will generate all library files inside the project. You can check the 'vendor' folder.
- Upload the whole project folder to the server filesystem.

Answer (score 5):

This might be a little late but adding this answer for someone struggling with the same issue regarding `composer2` on hostinger with php7+/laravel8.

Hostinger comes with `composer` and `composer2` on shared hosting with, and by default all the projects are set to use composer i.e., `composer 1.1.0`, what you could do is either modify the files under `/usr/local/bin` which most probably is not going to be possible due to the fact that this directory is not writable, so here's the solution:

1. SSH into your shared hosting using your preferred ssh client.
2. Make sure you are in your home directory `cd ~`
3. Edit your shell configurations file `nano .bashrc` (for Bash) or `nano .zshrc` (for Zsh)
4. Add the following line to the end of the file: `alias composer="php /usr/local/bin/composer2.phar"` (This will use composer 2.5.5 at the time of writing this answer)
5. Save the file by pressing `CTRL+X`, then `Y`, then `ENTER`
6. Reload your shell configuration by running the command `source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.zshrc`, depending on which shell you're using.

This should be it, now running `composer --version` will give you `Composer version 2.5.5` instead of `1.1.0`

**Note**: be advised that this will apply composer at global level, affecting all of your projects using composer under the same hosting, proceed with caution.

Comment: Thanks, yes that's the correct way to update the composer in hostinger, in my case i could't find .bashrc or .zshrc so i created it and inserted the line you mentioned above then it works

Comment: @KamalCherkaoui ```nano filename``` works by either creating or updating existing file. Doesn't matter if the file does not exist it will be created.

Comment: Not enougth for me after restarting SSH client, added to  ~/.profile and it persist next connexion

Comment: Hey, thank you for pointing that out, seems like hostinger's hosting is frozen for new files creation. You are corrent, Why don't you suggest an edit to this answer as an update with your solution.

Comment: It works with hostinger server. Thanks